# Sublime Text 2と3は何が大きく違うんですか？

Tags: sublimetext

Sublime Text 2を使っているのですが、長らくβなバージョン3に移行したいななどと考えています。

バージョン3は、2と比べて何か大きく良くなかったところなどありますか？
また、3はやはりβということで不安定ですか？それとも十分使用に耐えられますか？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

あまり使い込んでないですが、個人的な感想としては、

起動(ウィンドウが表示されるまで)は早くなったと思います。これはプラグインの読み込みを起動してから行うようになったからじゃないかと思います。(起動して直ぐにコンソール開くと読み込み中な雰囲気なので)

あとはバンドルしているpythonのバージョンが、Sublime Text 2は2.6なのに対し、Sublime Text(3)はpython 3系がバンドルされています。手元のものは3.3でしたが今後変わるかもしれません。
これもあって 3用のプラグインがないというケースも考えられますが、ほとんどの場合は両方対応してると思います。

余談ですが、個人的にライセンス買ったものの最近Sublime Textの動きが少ないので Github Atom.io (まだアルファ版だが普通に使えているし、SJIS公式対応)や Adobe brackets (UTF8以外まだ未対応ではあるがver 1リリース済み)に乗り換えようかなとも考えてます。
(どちらもPythonじゃないのが残念ですが)

---

### 追記：

バンドルされているバージョンについては上記を修正しました。

それ以外に思い出した点としては、2では `Default`の設定ファイル( settings, key-bindindings )のファイルを直接編集して設定を変更することができたと思いますが、3ではそれはできなくなっていて、user定義ファイルで設定する事が強制されるようになりました。Defaultの方をいじっていると最初戸惑うかもしれません。

Answer (score 5):

> 3は2と比べて何か大きく良くなかったところなどありますか？

Sublime Text3になってより柔軟にSublimeのUI部分を変更しやすくはなっています。

> 3はやはりβということで不安定ですか？
>   それとも十分使用に耐えられますか？

Sublime Text Blogの「[Sublime Text 3 Public Beta](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-3-public-beta) 」によると：

> Build 3047 is the fastest, most stable, most polished version of Sublime Text yet.

最新のSublime Text 3は最も早く最も安定的で最も洗練されてSublime Textだそうです。

より詳しいSublime Text2 と3の大きな違いについては、Sublime Textの[CAHNGELOG](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/)を参照していただければと思います

### 参照サイト

- [Sublime Blog](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/)
- [Migrate from Sublime text 2 to Sublime text3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17537817/2248060)

Answer (score 3):

公式の売り文句も含めて、私が知っている違いは、

- パフォーマンス改善 (起動や置換)
- シンボルインデックスが強化。プロジェクト単位をスキャンするように
- プロジェクト内で、複数のワークスペースを作れる (ワークスペース＝タブをまとめたもの)
- HTML のタグを `'/'` を入力で閉じられる
- タブの部分がスクロールする
- 画像を開ける
- サイドバーのアイコンが豊富になった
- プラグインのAPIが改良された
- プラグイン毎にユーザ用の設定を作るように推奨
- ST2 にあるのに、 ST3 ではプラグインが未対応のものがある ([このサイトでチェックできる](http://www.caniswitchtosublimetext3.com/))
- まだまだまだまだベータ版

私にとって大きいのは以下です。

- Python のバージョンが 2.x 系から 3.x 系に移行した
- Goto メニューに新機能

  - Goto Definition [`F12`]
  - Goto Symbol in Project [`Ctrl+Shift+'R'`]
  - Jump Back [`Alt+'-'`]
  - Jump Forward　[`Alt+Shift+'-'`]
- ST2, ST3 を同時にインストール可能。

ユーザが普段気にする機能は、シンボルインデックス機能の強化ぐらいではないでしょうか、　`F12` と `Ctrl+Shift+'R'` は便利です。